load site from cacheStorage with iframe tag
When offline, you can access cacheStorage using fetch(), etc.
The address entered in the src tag of <iframe> will not be bypassed to cacheStorage and will fail to view the site.
Using fetch() to collect text information from cacheStorage, convert it to a blob, and use URL.createObjectURL() to get the blob address, it works in the <iframe> tag.
However, files such as scripts linked to the html file also fail to load from cacheStorage, causing the page to break.
Any good ideas?
------
How to reproduce the action
this link is the page I'm working on that supports Offline-pwa:
is2you2.github.io/godotchat_pwa
When you enter a page, it stores about 1527 page files in cacheStorage. Once all are stored, it will work normally offline.
To configure the environment that reproduce the action:
1. Second tab at the bottom: In the Channels tab, click the + button to create a channel with any name.
2. Enter the created channel and send a *.blend file. Example *.blend files can be received from this link. (pjcone.ddns.net:9002/cdn/…)
3. When a file is sent to the channel, a gray square box is created. Clicking on the box will open the *.blend file.
4. There are some errors, but the important thing is that it opens. That's all for the online test.
5. When you change the network status to offline and try to open the file sent to the channel again, it doesn't open.
When opening a *.blend file, the action is to create an iframe object in JavaScript and open "assets/js.blend/index.html" in src. When fetch() this address, page information is normally received from cacheStorage. However, it is not in the iframe.

What iframes can access has been getting more and more restricted in recent years in order to stop user tracking and increase browser security.
There are newer features such as setting a Permission Policy via either a http header or the allow attribute on the iframe tag itself. That might help.
The other option is the new <fencedframe> tag, which is a new type of frame that has the ability to share some resources with the parent page, which includes storage. However, currently it only works in Chrome based browsers.

Thanks for the feedback!
Unfortunately, setting the property did not solve it.
It seems a bit perverted, but I think I should read all the files needed for processing with fetch, generate all blob addresses, and then replace all the addresses of prepared scripts etc. inside the files with the blob addresses.
At this point, I think it is difficult to access the cache storage through the service worker from the iframe.

I think the fencedframe object you mentioned is still too early to use. Still, thanks for the good info :)
